# making java tic tac toe vs computer

Tags: java

Thats my tictactoe game and i have this problem i cant find out...When i compile my programm
Welcome To Tic Tac Toe Professor Falken!

```
***Use Numbers 1-9 To Select A Square***

_1_|_2_|_3_|

_4_|_5_|_6_|

_7_|_8_|_9_|

  You Go First!

___|___|___|

___|___|___|

___|___|___|

Player X, enter move (1 - 9):

10

INVALID MOVE: Enter number 1 - 9 only:

5

___|___|___|

___|_X_|___|

___|___|___|

Player O, enter move (1 - 9):

___|___|___|

___|_X_|_O_|

___|___|___|

Player X, enter move (1 - 9):

4

___|___|___|

_X_|_X_|_O_|

___|___|___|
Player O, enter move (1 - 9):
```

And stops there, i dont know why can anyone help me?

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TicTacToe {

    private Scanner in;
    private boardPiece[][] board = {{new boardPiece(),new boardPiece(),new boardPiece()},
                                    {new boardPiece(),new boardPiece(),new boardPiece()},
                                    {new boardPiece(),new boardPiece(),new boardPiece()}};
    private char turn = 'X';
    private boolean win = false;
    private int count = 0;
    private Random random = new Random();
    private int randomNumber = random.nextInt(9);

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
    int replay;
    TicTacToe game = new TicTacToe();
    game.in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Welcome To Tic Tac Toe Professor Falken!");
    System.out.println("***Use Numbers 1-9 To Select A Square***");
    System.out.println("_1_|_2_|_3_|");
    System.out.println("_4_|_5_|_6_|");
    System.out.println("_7_|_8_|_9_|");
    System.out.println("           n  You Go First!");
    game.play();
    System.out.println("Would you like to play again?(1 = Yes & 2 = No): ");
    replay = game.in.nextInt();
    while(replay != 2){
    game.init();
    game.play();
    System.out.println("Would you like to play again?(1 = Yes & 2 = No): ");
    replay = game.in.nextInt();
    }
    game.in.close();
    System.out.println("How about a nice game of chess :p");
    }

    public void play()
    {
    printBoard();
    while(!win)
    move();
    }

    public void printBoard()
    {
    for(int x=0; x<3; x++){
    for(int y=0; y<3; y++){
    System.out.print(board[x][y].piece);
    }
    System.out.println();
    }
    }

    public void move()
    {
    int move = 0;
    String valid = "";
    System.out.println("Player " + turn + ", enter move (1 - 9): ");
    if(turn == 'O') {
        move = randomNumber; }
    else {
        move = in.nextInt();
    }

    valid = checkMove(move);
    while(valid != "ok")
    {
        if(turn == 'X') {
            System.out.println("INVALID MOVE: "+ valid);
            move = in.nextInt();

        }
        else {
            move = randomNumber;

        }
        valid = checkMove(move);
    }

    count++;
    board[(move-1)/3][(move-1)%3].piece = "_"+turn+"_|";
    board[(move-1)/3][(move-1)%3].player = turn;
    board[(move-1)/3][(move-1)%3].used = true;

    printBoard();

    if(count >= 5)
    checkWin(move);

    if(turn == 'X') 
        turn = 'O';

    else 
    turn = 'X';
    }

    public String checkMove(int move)
    {
    if(move < 1 || move > 9)
    return "Enter number 1 - 9 only: ";
    else
    if(board[(move-1)/3][(move-1)%3].used)
    return "That move has been used. Enter another move (1 - 9): ";
    else
    return "ok";
    }

    public void checkWin(int move)
    {
    for(int x = 0; x<3; x++){ //Horizontal 
    if((board[x][0].used && board[x][1].used && board[x][2].used) && 
    (board[x][0].player == board[x][1].player && board[x][0].player == board[x][2].player)){
    System.out.println("Congratulations Player " + turn + "!!! You win!");
    win = true;
    return;
    }
    }
    for(int y = 0; y<3; y++)
    {
    if((board[0][y].used && board[1][y].used && board[2][y].used) && 
    (board[0][y].player == board[1][y].player && board[0][y].player == board[2][y].player)){
    System.out.println("Congratulations Player " + turn + "!!! You win!");
    win = true;
    return;
    }
    }

    if((board[0][0].used && board[1][1].used && board[2][2].used) && 
    (board[0][0].player == board[1][1].player && board[0][0].player == board[2][2].player)){
    System.out.println("Congratulations Player " + turn + "!!! You win!");
    win = true;
    return;
    }

    if((board[2][0].used && board[1][1].used && board[0][2].used) && 
    (board[2][0].player == board[1][1].player && board[2][0].player == board[0][2].player))
    {
    System.out.println("Congratulations Player " + turn + "!!! You win!");
    win = true;
    return;
    }       

    if(count==9){
    System.out.println("Draw! Nobody Wins (´???`)");
    win = true;
    return;
    }
    }

    public void init()
    {
    for(int x=0;x<3;x++){
    for(int y=0;y<3;y++){
    board[x][y] = new boardPiece();
    }          
    }
    turn = 'X';
    win = false;
    count = 0;
    }

    class boardPiece{
    public String piece;
    public char player;
    public boolean used;

    boardPiece(){
    piece = "___|";
    used = false;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: When it's the computer's move, after `move = randomNumber;` try  `System.out.println("Beep boop my AI move is " + move);` . You'll notice it's the same number each and every time. This is because you assign `randomNumber` once and then it retains that value until the program exits. If you want a new random number, you have to do `move = random.nextInt(9);` (and you probably wanted to add `+ 1` to that so it's in the range `1-9` instead of `0-8`)

Comment: `while(valid != "ok")`This is not the correct way to compare Strings. You should use  `valid.equals("ok")` or `valid.equalsIgnoreCase("ok)`. Better yet, why not make `valid` a boolean instead of a String?

Answer (score 1):

I made a some changes in move and checkMove

```
public void move() {
    int move = 0;
    Boolean valid = false;
    System.out.println("Player " + turn + ", enter move (1 - 9): ");
    if (turn == 'O') {
        move = randomNumber;
    } else {
        move = in.nextInt();
    }

    valid = checkMove(move);
    while (!valid) {
        if (turn == 'X') {
            move = in.nextInt();
        } else {
            move = random.nextInt(9);
        }
        valid = checkMove(move);
    }

    count++;
    board[(move - 1) / 3][(move - 1) % 3].piece = "_" + turn + "_|";
    board[(move - 1) / 3][(move - 1) % 3].player = turn;
    board[(move - 1) / 3][(move - 1) % 3].used = true;

    printBoard();

    if (count >= 5) {
        checkWin(move);
    }
    if (turn == 'X') {
        turn = 'O';
    }else {
        turn = 'X';
    }
}

public Boolean checkMove(int move) {
    if (move < 1 || move > 9) {
        System.out.println("INVALID MOVE: Enter number 1 - 9 only: ");
        return false;
    }else if (board[(move - 1) / 3][(move - 1) % 3].used) {
        System.out.println("INVALID MOVE: That move has been used. Enter another move (1 - 9): ");
        return false;
    }else {
        return true;
    }
}
```